# Is Windows Phone 7 for industrial use?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, windows-mobile

I'm a .NET developer. I need to create mobile applications for managing inventory in a warehouse.

I'd like to use Microsoft's current mobile platform.

Is there a non-telephone version of Windows Phone 7? I don't need any of the personalized contacts, photos, games, music, etc. stuff either. I need rugged devices with bar code scanners. Are there any industrial devices that run Windows Phone 7?

### Update

I found this versioning/naming mess:

Windows Phone 7 is currently based on Windows Embedded CE 6.0 R3 with some features borrowed from Windows Embedded CE 7.0. Windows Embedded Compact 7 (formerly known as Windows Embedded CE 7.0) was released on March 1, 2011. The CTP version of the Platform Builder IDE for Windows Embedded Compact 7 is designed as plug-in for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 and requires Service Pack 1. On 10 January 2011, Microsoft announced Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5. The operating system has compatibility with Windows Mobile 6.5.

[image: Shut up and take my money!]

Nicholas Piasecki [wrote](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=6de6c381-aa4f-42a0-acb2-ff2d168c6614):

> As someone who has built Windows Mobile applications for exactly that
>   purpose (a ruggedized warehouse barcode scanner), my best advice is to
>   break from the Microsoft platform here; it's a mess and Microsoft
>   management is too distracted with Windows Phone and an internal
>   DevDiv/WinDev war:
>
> [No support for Windows CE and Compact Framework
>   development in VS2010](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/595712/no-support-for-windows-ce-and-compact-framework-development-in-vs2010)

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a non-telephone version of Windows Phone 7? I don't need any of the personalized contacts, photos, games, music, etc. stuff either. I need rugged devices with bar code scanners. Are there any industrial devices that run Windows Phone 7?

I think what you need is a device running Windows CE (renamed Windows Embedded Compact for version 7)

There are devices out there like http://www.barcodesinc.com/cats/portable-data-terminals/wince.htm - I don't know if there are any out there running CE7, but there should be plenty running CE5 or later - all of which can support .Net CF2 or .Net CF 3.5 - depending on what the manufacturer has included.

Answer (score 2):

In short, no. Windows Phone is currently only available as a consumer phone operating system, nothing more. As a .NET developer, the only things I can recommend for you to consider are Windows Mobile 6.5 devices, as there are many more industrial options already available.

Comment: Problem with this is that MS is also relegating WinMo development to the history bin. The SDKs don't support Visual Studio later than 2008 and the Windows Mobile Device Center is no longer supported in Windows 8, which means now you need to either run a VM with Win7 (but VMs don't always play nice with connected devices) and Visual Studio 2008, or have a second development machine on your desk for this legacy stuff. MS is really leaving commercial/industrial developers in a major lurch here.

Answer (score 1):

As at March 2014 we're still waiting for the first [Windows Embedded 8 Handheld (WE8H) Supported Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932966/windows-embedded-8-handheld-we8h-supported-devices), which is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are talking about WP7 in its current state itsn't suitable(i mean it could do alot of it but you couldn't get rid of the options)

You might by able to do alot more customization when the new update comes out(its a big one) 
In its current state you cant even select a custom ringtone, Switch lock off permanently etc etc. 
I have a good wp7 omnia 7 its metal with a strong screen but like i said not the most customisable.