# Windows Embedded 8 Handheld (WE8H) Supported Devices

Tags: windows-phone-8, embedded, enterprise

Needed to find a way to create a "Kiosk mode" Windows 8 phone Application.

After one and a half weeks of google intensive search, i've realized it is not possible to do. Then - Found two ways to workaround the problem -

1. Kid's Corner.
2. Windows 8 Embedded Handheld o.s.

The second solution looks better to me. i've found the Windows 8 Embedded Handheld SDK, and now i have the ability to start coding.

but, one second before i start, i couldn't find any device who supports this o.s (?!?)

does some one know any device?

thank.

Comment: You'll have to contact Microsoft or a Microsoft partner who deals with such devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Panasonic allegedly have a device due out in June 2014.  http://akihabaranews.com/2014/02/24/article-en/panasonic-new-toughpad-allows-full-control-while-wet-and-gloves-1935147623

Better review:  http://reviews.cnet.com/tablets/panasonic-toughpad-fz-e1/4505-3126_7-35835293.html

Answer (score 5):

For what I know (I work for Motorola Solutions), at this time (January 2014) Microsoft has not yet released the Final Image of Windows Embedded 8 Handheld to the [5 enabled manufacturer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/news/features/2013/jan13/01-14handheld.aspx).

After Microsoft releases the image you can assume that 6-9 months are necessary to build and test the low level drivers for the new components (barcode scanner, Enterprise WiFi, etc) before having the device available on the market. Even if we already have HW devices, currently running other OSes (Android 4.1), with the right HW in place (Qualcomm SoC supported by WE8H).

Depending on the timing of your project, WE8H may be too far away in the future.

At this moment all the HW vendor are planning to support WE8H but no clear timings because Microsoft has not yet, as today, announced availability of the OS. As an example, Bluebird, already has it show on devices like the BM180, but [the specs read](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&ved=0CIsBEBYwCQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffr.mypidion.com%2Finc%2Fboard_down.asp%3Ffile%3D%255BBrochure%255DBM180_EN.pdf%26kind%3Dproduct&ei=uJbTUpjwHqaIzAOCgoGgBg&usg=AFQjCNFlCEsxKw2DR6tTIXSc8Iz4bwNljw&sig2=erVPaYLREzcb-EGo-o_mqg&bvm=bv.59026428,d.bGQ):

**OS**

- Android 4.2
- Windows Embedded 8 Handheld(Planning)

If Mobile Device Management solutions like [AirWatch](http://www.air-watch.com/solutions/windows-phone) or [MobileIron](http://www.mobileiron.com/en/section-tab/windows-phone-management-resources) does not provide what you're looking for on WP8, maybe you need to find creative ways to do it (a cover that physically covers the home button?) or change target OS.

**Update on Windows Embedded 8.1 HandHeld**

Late April news is that now Microsoft released WE8.1HH to the manufacturer and there's a news SDK RC available to be used together with the one released last year for WE8HH. At least this looking at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn715922.aspx).

More information can be found on the [relevant Windows Embedded MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows-embedded/archive/2014/04/23/windows-embedded-8-1-handheld-has-been-released-to-manufacturing-sdk-is-now-generally-available.aspx?Redirected=true).
To the original 5 WE8HH licensee now Microsoft added Panasonic that announced a new devices supposed to be available later this year.

**Update on Panasonic FZ-E1**

[Panasonic to launch FZ-E1 with Windows Embedded 8.1 Handheld in August](http://www.wpcentral.com/panasonic-launch-fz-e1-windows-embedded-81-handheld-august)

Answer (score 0):

At present I don't belive there are any devices availiable for general purchase.

Motoroloa will likley be one of the first to release a device, check out their launchpad community pages:

https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/groups/windows-embedded-8-handheld-community